# Copy & paste format - from React Native web to a row in Excel / spreadsheets

Tags: css, react-native, expo

I'm working on a React-Native Expo app and I have a table to display some data. I want people to be able to copy and paste data from this table and into spreadsheet programs like Excel or Google Sheets while preserving the shape of the data, exactly like how HTML tables do, for example this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>name1</div></td>
    <td><div>email1</div></td>
    <td><div>phonenumber1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>name2</div></td>
    <td><div>email2</div></td>
    <td><div>phonenumber2</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I do this from my web page it copies and pastes all of the data in a single column.

To visualize, here's the desired outcome:

[image]

And here's the actual outcome:

[image]

This is because of the 'flex' attribute being the only way to display View components in a row:

```
<View key={index} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text style={{ ...TextStyles.cell }}>{entry.Name}</Text>
    <Text style={{ ...TextStyles.cell }}>{entry.Email}</Text>
    <Text style={{ ...TextStyles.cell }}>{entry.Phonenumber}</Text>
</View>
```

It automatically turns the components into block format, therefore when copying and pasting, the format is a column with a new line after every block. Ideally, I think this would be solved with `inline-block` styling, but it's unavailable on React Native to my knowledge.

I've attempted a few things:

1. Adding padding or a margin like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849953/copy-paste-with-flex-layout-in-react-native-web)
2. Wrapping all of the  components inside of another  component.
3. Adding some combination of `{'\t'}` or `'        '` or `{'\n'}` to the end of every cell (Excel does not register any of them)
4. Using React-Native-Clipboard to detect keyboard inputs and format the text from there (very limited options for checking the text)
5. Using a plugin, I tried React-Native-Paper's DataTable component, it also had this issue.

I know that using some plugin to just render an HTML table might work, but I'm very hesitant to do that as it's caused a lot of issues for me with Expo and submission to the app store. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an ideal solution because it involves an external package but I've achieved the desired outcome by using `<Table>`, `<TBody>`, `<TR>` and `<TD>` from the @expo/html-elements package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/html-elements